# If I add chrome/firefox extension under my user, will it affect other users?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, chrome-extension

I want to severely restrict my internet access. For my personal computer (which uses windows 10), I am happy with the solution provided by ColdTurkey. However, through x2go I can also log into my workplace ubuntu server, which is used by all my colleagues, though we have different users there of course. I don't have any sudo rights there.

Now, in this work computer we have chrome and firefox installed - I assume globally for all users. If I want to add LeechBlock extension to chrome and some other extension to firefox (LeechBlock doesn't seem to be available there), would it in any way affect other users on that machine, who are using chrome and firefox? I assume not, but I'd want to be absolutely sure, because I would like to block basically most of the access to internet, and I don't want others to know about it, and I don't want to get into trouble for doing something stupid (I want to set up the extensions in a way that I couldn't remove them later).

Comment: Did you install those extensions from your package manager or from the Firefox addon page?